# How to detect dpi automaticly and set zoom?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, hdmi

I have an Raspberry Pi 4b with Rasbian OS. I want to connect this device to an Full-HD or 4K (Retina) display (not at the same time). This works, but there is no automaticly scaling on 4k like on Windows 10 for example. So everything is way to small.

Is ther a way to detect hight dpi at startup and set scaling?

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can think off is to use the [EDID=*] filter in config.txt BUT this only operates a boot time.

Full documentation is [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md) but in simple terms:

1. Run `tvservice -n` from the command line for with monitors to ID the monitor
2. Add a section for each monitor in config.txt that sets the correct monitor mode:

   [EDID=MonitorID]
   hdmi_group=X
   hdmi_mode=XX

Once you have the OS set for the correct screen, you may then need to run something like `xrandr --dpi xxx` to force the desktop to scale correctly (it may do this automatically but I've no Pi 4).

Obviously, this could be scripted using the output of tvservice to make the selection and run automatically as the desktop starts.

Very messy and crude given my old IBM AT could detect the monitor type many many many years ago...

Answer (score 3):

For two displays, you could just define the optimal resolution/dpi for each device, and make a script which detects which display is connected, and set the desired resolution/dpi using [`xrandr`](https://linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_set_DPI_in_Xorg) with `--mode`, `--dpi` and `--scale` parameters.

For a general solution, check if `xrandr | grep connected` or `sudo get-edid | parse-edid | grep DisplaySize` report the correct size of your displays in mm. Then you'll need to write a script which parses the string (there are examples in the link above), calculates the DPI as `Resolution/Physical_size` and set it with `xrandr` as above. Some apps may be visually broken with arbitrary DPI, in which case it is recommended to round the calculated DPI to the closest value corresponding to 25% increments: 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, etc.

A good place to run such a script (apart from startup / periodic `cron` job) is an `udev` rule:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/pi/.Xauthority", RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

Note there are also environment variables which affect only apps using a certain GUI library:

- For QT, there's `QT_FONT_DPI=144`
- For GTK2/3, there's `GDK_SCALE=1.5`, `GDK_DPI_SCALE=1.5` and `ELM_SCALE=1.5`